# Usage of "back" as a verb. Can we use "We will back soon"?

Tags: verbs, differences, adjectives

Can we use "We will back soon"?

Or is the correct form "We will be back soon"?

What about "We'll be back soon"?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Why do you think "We will back soon" is correct?  "We will ..." & "We'll .." are  the same - but one would be better when written & the other would be more common when spoken.

Comment: @TrevorD someone told me that 'we will back soon' is correct and got me confused. so ur sure its wrong?

Comment: "We will back soon" means "we will go backwards soon " as if you are going to drive a car backwards!

Answer (score 1):

*We will be back soon* and *we'll be back soon are both correct*. *We will back soon* is wrong because *back* is an adjective not a verb and thus needs to be introduced with a verb, such as *be*.

Edit:

*We will back soon* could actually be grammatically correct, but *back* would have to take on a different meaning when used as a verb -- "to support" or "advocate for," which is not what you're talking about. (And even so, that version of *back* might require an object -- e.g. *we will back him soon*.)

Answer (score 1):

The verb "back" means something entirely than you think it does. The usual meaning of "to back" is to give support (financial, moral etc. ) to some cause. There is "to back away" meaning turning away and "to back off", there is "to back" meaning "covering the back of an item", wind can "back" (turn into a direction anti-clockwise, which is the opposite of "veer"), and in sailing "to back" means putting up a sail to slow down a boat.

The only situation where "we will back soon" is correct would be if two sailors discussed putting up a sail to slow down a boat.

Comment: Related to "to back away" and "to back off" is ["to back into"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/back+into+a+corner), which seems to be used primarily (exclusively?) in the contexts "back into a corner" (intransitive) and "back somebody into a corner".